# django retrieving related objects

Tags: python, django

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    publisher = models.ManyToManyField(Publisher,related_name='b', null=True)
    _published_at = models.DateTimeField()
from polls.models import Book, Publisher
p1=Publisher.objects.get(id=1)
p1.b.clear()
p1.save()
b6=Book.objects.get(id=6)
p1.b.add(b6)
b6._published_at = datetime.now()
p1.save()
b5=Book.objects.get(id=5)
p1.b.add(b5)
b5._published_at = datetime.now()
p1.save()
b7=Book.objects.get(id=7)
p1.b.add(b7)
b7._published_at = datetime.now()
p1.save()

p2 = Publisher.objects.get(id=2)
p2.b.clear()
p2.save()
b7=Book.objects.get(id=7)
p2.b.add(b7)
b7._published_at = datetime.now()
p2.save()
b6=Book.objects.get(id=6)
p2.b.add(b6)
b6._published_at = datetime.now()
p2.save()
b5=Book.objects.get(id=5)
p2.b.add(b5)
b5._published_at = datetime.now()
p2.save()

print p1.b.order_by("_published_at")
print p2.b.order_by("_published_at")
```

It prints

```
[Book: b7, Book: b6, Book: b5]
[Book: b7, Book: b6, Book: b5]
```

While I want it to print in the same order as I added them like this

```
[Book: b6, Book: b5, Book: b7]
[Book: b7, Book: b6, Book: b5]
```

Comment: check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by

Comment: i am not able to find my answer.

Comment: So you want it in a different order than they were created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add them you lose track of the order in which you add them because it only sets the foreign key of the Book.

What you can do is add a `DateTimeField`() to your Book and set it when you add it to a publisher and order_by it.

something like:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    _published_at = models.DateTimeField()
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher,related_name='b', null=True)
```

the when you add it

```
p=Publisher.objects.get(id=2)
p.b.clear()
p.save()
b6=Book.objects.get(id=6)
p.b.add(b6)
b6._published = datetime.now()
b6.save()
p.save()
b5=Book.objects.get(id=5)
p.b.add(b5)
b5._published = datetime.now()
b5.save()
p.save()
b7=Book.objects.get(id=7)
p.b.add(b7)
b7._published = datetime.now()
b7.save()
p.save()
```

and when you prints it:

```
p.b.order_by("_published_at")
```

EDIT: 
for your question about the `ManyToManyField` you need a custom "through" model
see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    publisher = models.ManyToManyField(Publisher,related_name='b',through="Publication",null=True)
    _published_at = models.DateTimeField()

class Publication(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    _published_at = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['_published_at']
```

Also you cannot use `add()` to add new publisher you need to define the new models to do so.

so to add Publisher p3 to book b7 you need to do

```
Publication.objects.create(book=b7, publisher=p3, _published_at=datetime.now())
```

they should be ordered automatically by now

Comment: Sorry for late responding. Yes, your answer is correct for foreinkey. Now lets change foreignkey to manytomany and then take another publisher object(say p2) and add book objects in different order than previous one(b6, b5, b7)  like b5, b6, b7. And then try to get book queryset for both publishers(p1 and p2) in same order as they were added  respectively. Please give back a response.